# Recenter world map and shapefiles in R

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, shapefile

I'm new to spatial data analyses in R and am stuck on a particular issue. I have overlaid multiple shapefiles on a world map which is centered on the Atlantic Ocean (default centering). All of my layers import fine in this view, but what I would really like to do is re-center everything over the Indo-Pacific. I know how to re-center just the world map, but when I add my shapefiles to the re-centered map they no longer plot properly (they do not wrap and are cut off beyond a certain longitude). I'm assuming I may need to reformat the coordinates specified within each shapefile? Not sure how to resolve this issue.

How everything looks centered over the Atlantic (default):[image: How everything looks centered over the Atlantic:]

How I want my map centered, but shapefile extents are cut off/do not wrap: [image: How I want my map centered, but shapefile extents dow not wrap and are cut off:]

Here is my code:

```
map("worldHires") #Used for default centering, works fine with 
                  shapefiles

map("worldHires", wrap=c(0,360), ylim=c(-60,60)) #Used for 
reformatted centering, does not work well with shapefiles

shapefile1 <- rgdal::readOGR("shapefile1.shp")
plot(shapefile1, add=TRUE, col=scales::alpha("darkblue", 0.6), 
    border=FALSE)

shapefile2 <- rgdal::readOGR("shapefile2.shp")
plot(shapefile2, add=TRUE, col=scales::alpha("darkgreen", 0.6), 
    border=FALSE)

shapefile3 <- rgdal::readOGR("shapefile3.shp")
plot(shapefile3, add=TRUE, col=scales::alpha("darkred", 0.6), 
    border=FALSE)

map.axes()
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for fixing this issue? Thanks ahead of time for the help!

Comment: Does this help https://rdrr.io/cran/maptools/man/nowrapRecenter.html?